# Laravel Response::download not working and pdf file not downloaded when clicked button

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to achieve a link in a menu bar, such that when a user clicks on the link, a pdf file will be downloaded automatically, and it should not navigate to other pages.

Inside my main.blade.php, consists of a menu bar, I have this link:

```
<a href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>/php/timetable/public/download">Help</a>
```

where *$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']* is localhost.

Inside my routes.php:

```
Route::get('/download', array('uses'=>'MainController@getDownloadHelp'));
```

Inside my controller called MainController:

```
public function getDownloadHelp()
{
    $file= public_path(). "/public/download";
    $filename = 'help.pdf';
    $headers = array(
          'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
        );
    return Response::download($file, $filename, $headers);
}
```

The PDF file is stored under /public/download/help.pdf

The problem I'm facing right now is, when I clicked the 'Help' link on the menu bar, it redirects me to ***localhost/download*** which is not what I wanted. And also, the pdf is not downloaded.

I really need some help here! Where and what did I went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `{{ URL::to('/download') }}` instead of `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']...` 
or in your blade

```
echo link_to('download', $title, $attributes = array(), $secure = null);
```

it will write all the `<a></a>` thing

for the path in the controller maybe you can remove the public in the path of the file like this

```
public_path() . '/download/';
```